# How to Solve Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in android Q(10)

Tags: android-10.0

I am making a Status saving app now i getting problem with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in android Q(10) that dont support `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

This is my code:

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static final File WHATSAPP_STATUS_DIRECTORY =
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses");

    public static final String APP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"WhatsAppStatusProDir";
   
            
    public static final int THUMBSIZE = 128;
}
```

Please Find a Solution and yes i dont want to use  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

this pease of code..

Comment: And...what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is api 29 is not support getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: I already see this but i dont understand that.

Comment: if you understand it please solve this in my code

Comment: Use `getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: Sir it is showing error when adding it as it is error:Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext' in 'MyConstants' Please explain as in my code how i implement it.